# mysql - add a new column in a database when a row is added in another

Tags: mysql, database

I currently have a database that stores users, doors, and a table that has the access privileges. I mainly will be editing the database manually (using Sequel Pro on Mac if it matters). But there is also a php script that will query the database when the card reader next to each door scans a card.

For example, the door table stores location, door id, and if it's internal or external. The user table contains a user id, name, and notes. The access table needs to store the user, the door, and the time limit. The access table is currently set up where there's three columns: user id, door id, and table limits. I have found this isn't working. Every time I need to change the user id (which is the id of their access card and will change if they lose it or it breaks for example), or the door id (which is the mac address of the card reader and will change if a reader is replaced for example), I need to change 50+ rows, one for each door.

Ideally I want to have the access table setup like this:

```
+-------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|   User ID   |            (door 1 id)            |            (door 2 id)            |            (door 3 id)            |
+-------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
| (user 1 id) | (time limit for user 1 on door 1) | (time limit for user 1 on door 2) | (time limit for user 1 on door 3) |
| (user 2 id) | (time limit for user 2 on door 1) | (time limit for user 2 on door 2) | (time limit for user 2 on door 3) |
+-------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```

I want it like this both to make it visually easy to look at, and easy to edit without having to create more code to visually represent this to a user. But primarily, I want it this way so I can create a relationship for the user id in this table and make it reference the user id in the users table.

I tried to create a trigger to add a column, update the door id of a column, and delete a column when I add a door in the doors table, change the door id in the doors table, or delete a door in the doors table. However it appears that triggers can't control the columns.

Is there an alternate way of doing this?

Comment: have you tried calling a stored procedure from the trigger? the sp should then create the column you wanted and other stuff you wanted to do... https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10657/call-a-stored-procedure-from-a-trigger

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I was under the impression an SP or function couldn't add or change columns too.

Comment: can't do with function (assuming) but stored procedure should be able to

Comment: @maSTAShuFu can the SP take an argument (the door id)

Comment: SP can take any parameter same with the function but stored procedure are initially built to process but not return... nowadays stored procedure can return values if you wish..... you use SP if you think the trigger does not like to create columns

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I'll give an SP a shot, will report back

Comment: You have 50+ doors?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu yeah it's going to be a campus wide thing. I am anticipating around 50 doors. Maybe more maybe less, but something around there. Anyways, I created a stored procedure, and then in the trigger, told it to `CALL newcolfornewdoor(NEW.doorid);`. However upon trying to insert a new row, I get the error `Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.`

Comment: looking at the article above link i reckon the best you do is not make a trigger but call an SP to insert or update data but beneath it is your extra process.

Comment: @maSTAShuFu dang that sucks. Ok, thanks. Maybe it would just be easier to write a whole GUI for this system. I wanted to avoid it but maybe I'm gonna have to.